# How to clean function parameters in a virtual function chain?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make my virtual functions look cleaner for the end users. One of the issues that virtual function have is that they force the same type across the hold chain. However many times this is undesirable. Because it forces the user to upcast pointers. So I thought up this construct (onHello). You can see that allows changing the type in the final users classes. (onHi) is the traditional way of doing it. I was wondering if this method is used commonly or not, and why or why not?

```
struct base
{
    virtual void onHello( base& X ) { x_printf( "Hello - setting base" ); }
    virtual void onHi   ( base& X ) { x_printf( "Hi - setting base" ); }
};

template< typename T >
struct base_link : public base
{
    virtual void onHello( base& X ) override { /*do type checking here*/ ((T*)this)->onHello( *(T*)&X ); }
};

struct bar_yes : public base_link<bar_yes>
{
                 bar_yes( int Y ) : Yes( Y ) {}
            void onHello( bar_yes& Y )          { base::onHello( Y ); Yes = Y.Yes; }
    virtual void onHi   ( base&    X ) override { /*do type checking here*/ base::onHi( X ); Yes = ((bar_yes*)&X)->Yes; }

    int Yes;
};

struct bar_no : public base_link<bar_no>
{
                 bar_no ( int N ) : No( N ) {}
            void onHello( bar_no& N )          { base::onHello( N ); No = N.No;  }
    virtual void onHi   ( base&   X ) override { /*do type checking here*/ base::onHi( X ); No = ((bar_no*)&X)->No; }

    int No;
};

void main()
{
    bar_yes     TestYes[2] { 0, 1 };
    bar_no      TestNo[2]  {100,200};
    base*       pBase[]    { &TestYes[0], &TestNo[0] };

    pBase[0]->onHello( TestYes[1] );
    pBase[0]->onHi   ( TestYes[1] );
    pBase[1]->onHello( TestNo[1] );
    pBase[1]->onHi   ( TestNo[1] );
}
```

Comment: There is never any need to upcast pointers. And what is a "hold chain"?

Comment: What you make is called [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern) and kind of like [Parameterized Base Class](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Parameterized_Base_Class). But in your example I think this is a bad design, since it looks like your class do someone else's work.

Comment: NikolayKondratyev - Thank you for your comment I found it really useful. The class is not doing other work except the redirection with whatever safety overhead is desirable.

Comment: I meant that you pass ``base&`` to the interface method, so you want to do something with it, but it is different object and it should take care of itself. And also it is bad idea to downcast pointers. I can be wrong, maybe your example is too simple and in more complex situation all of this makes sense. But my another guess would be that you want something like [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), take a look.

Comment: In the example, the main function just have pointers to the base classes. This is typical in C++ and the main porpoise of virtual functions. If you wanted to have the functionality provided by onHi most people would have written the same code as onHi. However onHello provides an alternative and potentially cleaner way to handle the same case as onHi. Because onHello has factor out the pointer casting and potentially could also factor out other things like argument assertions. Safety wise I could claim onHello is better since reduces code for users. Performance wise should be the same, thanks.